# Using Lyx on Fedora 20: what does this error mean?

Tags: lyx

I get this error when trying to compile a pdf with Lyx 2.1:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev) (format=latex 2015.4.2)  28 JUL 2015 12:45 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled.
**rationale.tex (./rationale.tex LaTeX2e <2011/06/27> Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/texmf-compat/tex/latex/evergent/article.cls

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  

...                                    

                                                   l.1 <
     script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><script>var m={navigat...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit."
```

Here is the output .tex file minimal example:

```
%% LyX 2.1.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

It generates the same error for compilation.

Comment: The main error is: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`. Check the latex file you are working on and make sure it contains `\begin{document]`

Comment: @Leucippus He's using LyX, so it's impossible to avoid having `\begin{document}`, I think.

Comment: deamondave: Have you added anything to the preamble, and if yes, what? Can you make a minimal example (basically make a copy of your file and remove as much content and custom setup as possible without removing the error), export that to LaTeX code, and add it to your question?

Comment: yes. Lyx on Fedora 20.

Comment: The RPM that contains article.cls is supposed to be within texlive-latex. Here are my texlive-latex rpms installed: Installed Packages
texlive-latex.noarch                3:svn27907.0-6.fc20                 @updates

Comment: @daemondave As Torbjørn asked for, please provide a minimal example .lyx file (it is just a text file).  For more information, see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Ok I will try to put one together. thanks for your help.

Comment: latex didn't even finish reading `article.cls`.  is there anything in the .tex file *before* the `\documentclass` line?  something that includes a `<script>`, for instance?  (i'm totally ignorant about lyx, but when the log complains about line 1, ...)

Comment: Yes Barbara and that's why I am stumped. I looked using gedit at the text file and there is no text passage "script>window.googleJavaScriptRedirect=1</script><script>var m={navigat." inside the text file.

Answer (score 2):

The situation seems quite clear: the `article.cls` file is fetched from

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-local/texmf-compat/tex/latex/evergent/
```

while it should be in

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/
```

Somebody or something installed some `texmf-compat` subtree under `texmf-local` and this is the cause of your problem. Possibly the cause is having installed [LaTeX2HTML](http://www.latex2html.org), which is an obsolete and unsupported program.